# Move Image control in VB2010 WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, layout

In windows forms, you can easily change the ".left" value of a picturebox to move it. However, I have noticed that in VB2010 WPF, this is not the case.. Can anyone show me how to change an image control's .left (or equivalent) value in wpf? 
Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally placement in WPF depends on the container a control is a child of. If you want to adjust placements you can either use the `Margin` property which should work for almost all containers or place the Image in a `Canvas`, then you can use the `Canvas.Left` attached property for placement.

Additionally you could use `LayoutTransform` or `RenderTransform` properties to move your control around; you would use a `TranslateTransform` for that.

e.g.

```
    <Grid>
        <Button Margin="20,0,0,0" Content="Using Margin"/>
    </Grid>

    <Canvas Height="30">
        <Button Canvas.Left="20" Content="Using a Canvas"/>
    </Canvas>

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Using TranslateTransform">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="20"/>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

(Changing margin programmatically:)

```
        Thickness margin = Control.Margin;
        margin.Left += 1;
        Control.Margin = margin;
```

Comment: Thank you, most helpful,but how would I change the value of the margin at runtime? At the moment I have a dispatcher timer tick subroutine, in which I want the x value to increase by one, or any other specified amount, how do I set the margin up to do this?